# Tesseract-Ocr captcha : need to read text

Tags: opencv, ocr, tesseract, captcha

captcha-01

[image: captcha-01]

captcha-02

[image: captcha-02]

Already I have applied some image preprocessing. when i apply to this image to **pytesseract.image_to_string()** it's giving a bad result can you suggest me a better result.

Comment: You have to preprocess the image before throwing it into OCR. Please add your original input image

Answer (score 0):

Tesseract is not designed to break captcha. Tesseract expect clear images without minimum artifacts.

If captcha is implemented, there is reason for it. Instead of breaking it, contact admin of site to agree about cooperation instead of breaking rules.